# Is modal logic required to handle assumptions in logic? (Tic Tac Toe example)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, modal-logic

Suppose the Tic Tac Toe board is like this:
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
 1 & 2 & 3  \\ \hline
 4 & 5 & 6  \\ \hline
 7 & 8 & 9 
\end{array}
and I define a predicate `row1-win` by:
$$ X(1) \wedge X(2) \wedge X(3) \Rightarrow \mbox{row1-win} $$
meaning the first row have all three X's.

Now I want to define another predicate `row1-can-win` which means that player X is one move away from winning row1, specifically by playing X(1).  It describes this situation:
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
      & X & X  \\ \hline 
 * & * & *  \\ \hline
 * & * & *  
\end{array}
but I want to **re-use** the predicate `row1-win`.  So I say:
$$ \bigg ( X(1) \Rightarrow \mbox{row1-win} \bigg ) \Rightarrow \mbox{row1-can-win} $$
meaning that "If the assumption that X(1) is played implies `row1-win`, then this implies `row1-can-win`".

But it doesn't quite work because, whenever square 1 is empty, X(1) would be False, and the inner $\Rightarrow$ would be True, making the overall conclusion also True, regardless of what are in squares 2 and 3.  This is not the intended meaning, which requires X(2) and X(3) be True.

What has gone wrong with this formulation?

I think the problem is that the first $\Rightarrow$ may be wrong in the sense that it should not be interpreted as "material implication", but instead the notion of "strict implication" should be used.  The latter requires modal logic, ie, "A strictly implies B" is equivalent to $\square (A \Rightarrow B)$, meaning "A implies B necessarily".

Is my thinking correct?  Is there a way to express this using classical propositional logic only?

Comment: "Is modal logic required to handle assumptions in logic?" In general NO.

Comment: The fact that a digital computer can be programmed using standard programming languages to play tic-tac-toe and never lose (only wins and draws) suggests to me that classical logic would suffice. Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_translation

Answer (score 1):

This feels more like a programming question than a math question, but I will try to help anyway.

The main issue is that there are two different interpretations of $X(1)$ in your formulation.

- When you define $\operatorname{row1-win}$ by $X(1) \wedge X(2) \wedge X(3) \implies \operatorname{row1-win}$, $X(1)$ here means "in the current state of the board, box $1$ has an $X$".
- When you define $\operatorname{row1-can-win}$ by $(X(1) \implies \operatorname{row1-win}) \implies \operatorname{row1-can-win}$, $X(1)$ here means "in the scenario where I fill box $1$ with an $X$".

---

Allow me to propose an alternate formulation that works. Code your Tic-Tac-Toe board by functions $f : \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\} \to \{0,X,O\}$. The initial state is such that $f(n) = 0$ for all $n = 1,\dots,9$.

Now define two functions $\operatorname{Add-X}$ and $\operatorname{Add-O}$ as follows: For $\operatorname{Add-X}$, it takes in a function $f$ and a value $n = 1,\dots,9$, such that:
$$
\operatorname{Add-X}(f,n)(m) = 
\begin{cases}
X, &\text{if $m = n$} \\
f(m), &\text{if $m \neq n$} \\
\end{cases}
$$
I.e. we add an $X$ to box $n$ (I'm assuming that it is legal to add an $X$ to box $n$). $\operatorname{Add-O}$ can be defined similarly.

Now you can define the predicates in your question as follows: $\operatorname{row1-win}$ shall be a function that takes in $f$, and says:
$$
\operatorname{row1-win}(f) \iff f(1) = X \wedge f(2) = X \wedge f(3) = X
$$
and:
$$
\operatorname{row1-can-win}(f) \iff \operatorname{row1-win}(\operatorname{Add-X}(f,1)) \vee \operatorname{row1-win}(\operatorname{Add-X}(f,2)) \vee \operatorname{row1-win}(\operatorname{Add-X}(f,3))
$$

Comment: Interesting... what you do is turn the board representation into functions.  Then you can reason about *different* board states, which is what I needed.

Comment: In my formulation, I consider only one "board".  X(1) means square 1 has an X.  So my statement is:  "Assuming that square 1 has an X, then this is a row1 win."  That is not problematic, is it?

Comment: @YanKingYin It sounds problematic to me. If square $1$ already has an $X$, then you will have $\operatorname{row1-win}$ is true by default. If square $1$ does not have an $X$, then $X(1)$ must be false and hence $\operatorname{row1-win}$ is true. In other words, the statement $X(1) \implies \operatorname{row1-win}$ does not reflect what you want.

Comment: Wait... if square 1 does not have an X, then X(1) is false and row1-win is **false**.

Comment: @YanKingYin yes. Is that not what you want?

Comment: Well, the problem is very subtle.  If X(1) is played, then row1-win will be true.  I want to deduce from this that the other squares must then have X's also.  But I cannot express this in my logic.  If I write X(1) => row1-win, then it can mean that X(2) and X(3) are true, but it can _also_ mean that X(1) causes X(2) and X(3) to be true.  In my logic language, there is no way to express that "playing" X(1) would not affect other squares.  This is not even related to modal logic.  I don't know what to call it 

Comment: More insight: I should add the fact that playing a move on a square does not affect other squares, but this is not expressible in my current language.  Moreover I found that this is the so-called “frame problem” in artificial intelligence, ie, specifying what is true in one state of the world and exactly what is changed by an action in the world.  Anyway, that's for another forum.  Thanks ☺